# IntelliJ SQL error highlight

Tags: intellij-idea

I would like the errors related to the DDL or DataSource to be marked as propper errors (underlined in red or whatever). Instead, for instance, what I get when I reference a non existing table is just a yellow highlighting, as if it was a warning.

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA 12.

For instance, this query is correct.

```
SELECT S.CODE_SERVICE FROM SERVICE S;
```

But in this query:

```
SELECT S.CODE_ZZERVIZZE FROM SERVICE S;
```

the word CODE_ZZERVIZZE will be only highlighted and a kind of a warning message will be displayed when I hover the mouse over:

```
unable to resolve column 'CODE_ZZERVIZZE' less... (Ctrl+F1)
This inspection performs unresolved SQL references check.
```

What I would have expected is that the line was marked with a propper error so that I can clearly spot the compilation problem.

Comment: Could you please give an example of the error?

Comment: It's not really a compilation problem...the problem becomes apparent when you execute that line of SQL.  I also think that the error is appropriate, given that the column doesn't exist  (and everything else is syntatically correct).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With your cursor on the warning, bring up the quick fix menu (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>⌥</kbd><kbd>⏎</kbd>). From the quick fix menu select "Inspection 'Unresolved reference' options" > "Edit inspection profile setting". In the inspection setting dialog, change the severity to the desired level. Clicking the ellipsis button opens an open where you can add custom levels.

**Edit:**

Just to clarify, that will only change the error level (and thus highlighting and error strip) of the problematic word/variable. There is no way to change it so the whole line is highlighted rather than just the invalid variable if that is what you wanted.

Comment: Works like a sharm. Of course, now I get many errors in my script because IntelliJ doesn't recognise certain Oracle objects, but I can put a "-- noinspection SqlResolve" flag to it.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in following up... Make sure you have the SQL dialect set to "Oracle" for your project, or at least for the directory that contains the file. That should help IntelliJ IDEA recognize more Oracle specific syntax than the default "Generic". File > Settings [Project Settings] > SQL Dialects

Comment: If dialects other than "plain text" are not available, make sure you've installed the bundled SQL Support plugin.

Comment: with `--noinspection SqlResolve`, sql "coloring" is lost, with `/* @noinspection SqlResolve */` (inside a string) the formatting remain, and the alert vanish.